# How to make a javascript macro

Tags: javascript, macros

Is it possible to do something that can press 7 and space when I press f? i will use it in a game

I've tried but failed. My javascript skills don't seem that good.

Comment: check out https://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: It's sucks javascript have better reply time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.